# Vertical alignment multirow

Tags: multirow, multicolumn

I have this code here and I would like to know how can I center (vertically) the first column. Now I have {Feb, 2014 -- Present} at the top of the table.

```
   \begin{tabular}{l|p{12cm}}
   \ {Feb, 2014 --} & Master Thesis Student \\
   \ {Present} & {XXXXXXXXX}\\ 
   & {YYYYYYYYY}"
   \newline ZZZZZZZZZZZ
   \newline WWWWWWWW}}\\
   \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\ 
   \end{tabular}
```

Thanks in advance,

JAY

Answer (score 2):

`tabular`s are naturally centred vertically. So, I would nest two `tabular`s inside the outer `tabular`. The outer `tabular` provides the general layout/structure, while the inner `tabular`s provide the content, one column at a time:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}|@{}l@{}}
  \begin{tabular}{l}
    Feb, 2014 -- \\ Present
  \end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}{p{8cm}}
    Master Thesis Student \\
    XXXXXXXXX \\
    YYYYYYYYY \\
    ZZZZZZZZZZZ \\
    WWWWWWWW \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The outer `tabular` has no column separation, hence the use of `@{}`.

Answer (score 1):

Very simply with the `makecell` package. Note that the number of rows that's used with `\multirow(cell)` is not really the number of rows, but the number of `lines`, plus possibly some manual adjustment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array, makecell, multirow}
\renewcommand\cellalign{lc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l|p{12cm}}
  \multirowcell{5}{Feb, 2014 \\–--\,Present} & Master Thesis Student \\
    & {XXXXXXXXX} \\
    & {YYYYYYYYY}"
    \newline ZZZZZZZZZZZ
     \newline WWWWWWWW\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]